# Rails 3 JQuery Pagination on a nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, pagination, will-paginate

I have watched the railscasts on [Pagination with AJAX](http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax).  I am trying to duplicate his method using a nested model.  I seem to be confused because i don't have a view for the child model or a fully integrated controller.

Assume the Product has_many Comments.  How can I do the same pagination using will_paginate on comments within a product view?

UPDATE:

Here is most of my attempt (my attempt actually uses kaminari but it's basically the same as will_pagenate):

view/products/comments/_index.html.erb:

```
<div id="comments">
  <% comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :comments, comments do |comment_builder| %>
      <%= render 'products/comments/field', f: comment_builder %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= paginate comments %>
</div>
```

view/products/comments/_field.html.erb:

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_id, :value => f.object._id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= f.object.text %>
  <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_field" %>
</fieldset>
```

view/products/comments/_index.js.erb:

```
$("#comments").html("j render("products/comments/index")) %>");
```

assets/javascripts/product.js

```
$('.pagination a').live
  click: ->
    $(".pagination").html("Page is loading...")
    $.getScript(this.href)
    false
```

controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_product

  def index
    @comments = @product.comments.desc(:created_at).page(params[:page]).per(10)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @comments }
    end
  end

private

  def get_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id]) if params[:product_id]
    redirect_to root_path unless defined?(@product)
  end
end
```

views/products/show.html.erb (an excerpt)

```
<%= render "products/comments/index", f: f, comments: @comments%>
```

controllers/products_controller.rb

```
def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])

  @comments = @product.comments.desc(:created_at).page(params[:page]).per(1)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @product }
  end
end
```

view/products/comments/_index.js.erb never gets called.  Also is there a more rails-like way of doing this?

Comment: What is your question? What have you done so far?

Comment: There i added code which is basically my attempt